# Unity3D bluetooth serial feed splitter issue C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a Bluetooth module that is streaming a stream of strings into a Unity application. Similar to the string variable. These are x, y and z from an imu sensor. I am trying to separate the values into their own x, y, z variables ie: int x, int y and int z.

So when I try the code below. This is the error:

FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
System.Number.StringToNumber (System.String str, System.Globalization.NumberStyles options, System.Number+NumberBuffer& number, System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo info, System.Boolean parseDecimal) (at :0)

```
   Code (csharp):
   public void fishing()
   {
    string numo = "4,-1,5,7,8,10,5,-4,8,10,-30";
    string[] splitted = numo.Split(',');
    int[] nums = new int[splitted.Length];
    for (int i = 0; i < splitted.Length; i++)
    {
        //source of error.
        nums[i] = int.Parse(splitted[i], 
        System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowLeadingSign);
        int x = nums[0];
        int y = nums[1];
        int z = nums[2];
        Debug.Log(x);
        Debug.Log(y);
        Debug.Log(z);

    }
    }
```

I then tried to run the code without making the integer conversion. This is the error:

IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.

```
  Code (csharp):
  public void fishing()
  {
    string numo = "4,-1,5,7,8,10,5,-4,8,10,-30";
    string[] splitted = numo.Split(',');
    int[] nums = new int[splitted.Length];
    for (int i = 0; i < splitted.Length; i++)
    {
        string x = splitted[0];
        string y = splitted[1];
        string z = splitted[2];
        Debug.Log(x);
        Debug.Log(y);
        Debug.Log(z);

      }
    }
```

So as explained I have a string x,y,z,x,y,z,x,y,z coming from a Bluetooth module. I would like to receive the data and set it as different variables.

int x; int y, int z

Hope you can help

Comment: Your 'splitted' is an array, 'nums' has the same size. Next you pass array to int.Parse() when you should be passing a string. Next why do you expect int.Parse to return an array of two ints? Maybe you meant 'Parse(splitted[i])' ?

Comment: Hello nums[i] = int.Parse(splitted[i]); is used instead of nums = int.Parse(splitted);

Comment: What do you expect to happen? You parse string at index i, assign that to nums[i], but use constant 0, 1, 2 indices to read from nums?

Answer (score 0):

You did not have working code so I do not know if this is going to help you:

```
public void fishing()
        {
            string numo = "4,-1,5,7,8,10,5,-4,8,10,-30";
            string[] splitted = numo.Split(',');
            int[] nums = new int[splitted.Length];

            for (int i = 0; i < splitted.Length; i++)
            {
                if (splitted[i] == "") continue;
                var oneNum = int.Parse(splitted[i]);

                Debug.WriteLine(oneNum);
            }
        }
```

You should be able to debug the code when connected to the bluetooth device to check if you really get the correct input.

Comment: So I updated the code and successfully tested it but when I connect the Bluetooth module. I receive this error. IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array. Maybe because the function works in a fix length string and Bluetooth is continuos. Maybe you can help.

Comment: Can you debug and see what your strong is? Are you using exactly the same code?

Comment: Connecting the Bluetooth is creating the error. But I edited the post and that is the actual code. Hope you can help.

Comment: Strange, I do not see your edited code, I still see the fishing method with the string numo. Please have a look if you updated the post with the real code so I can help you.

Comment: Hello Aldert . Please have a look now.

Comment: I think your input string has a comma at the end like: string numo = "4,-1,5,7,8,10,5,-4,8,10,"; This causes the last string not to be a number. I fixed my  answer to deal with this

Comment: Hmm That's interesting the string is a constant stream from bluetooth. I will try remove ending comma. Many thanks Aldert.